# Fourier inversion formula

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that if $f \in L^{1}(R)$, and  $g$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, and $|g|\in L^{1}(R)$, then for almost every $x\in R$, $f(x)=\int g(u)e^{2 \pi iux}du$. But if $f(x)=\int g(u)e^{2 \pi iux}du$ for almost every $x\in R$, can I conclude $g$ is the Fourier Transform of $f$? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $g$ would equal the Fourier transform of $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: The fact you say you know in the first sentence is false. Once you learn a correct version of the inversion theorem, a correct version of this exercise follow. Hint: $\int g(u)e^{2\pi iux}\,dx=\hat g(-u)$.

Comment: My version seems to coincide with wikipedia's. (and my course's): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: Thanks @md2perpe! Unfortunately, I don't see how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the Fourier transform. The assumption is that $f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}g$ a.e. This means that $f$ works the same as $\mathcal{F}^{-1}g$ in integrals. Therefore,
$$
\mathcal{F}f(u) 
= \int f(x) e^{-i2\pi ux} dx
= \int (\mathcal{F}^{-1}g)(x) e^{-i2\pi ux} dx
= \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}g)(u)
\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}{=} g(u)
.
$$